# Mysql Windows path update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing issue while updating the substring of paths stored in table . I need to change sub string `C:\Program Files (x86)` as `%APPDATA%` for  column `path`.

Below is SQL and this SQL is not updating the path, showing 0 updated rows. What am i doing wrong here?

```
/*Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe*/                     

UPDATE software
SET path = REPLACE(path, 'C:\Program Files (x86)', '%APPDATA%')
WHERE path LIKE '%C:\Program Files (x86)%';
```

Comment: this SQL is not updating the path, showing 0 updated rows. While selecting the records, SQL working till '%C:%' string match. When I am adding '%C:/%', no record is selecting.

Comment: The orignal question shows a backslash character `'\'`, the string in the comment shows a forward slash character `'/'`.  Those are two different characters. The backslash character is a special character in the context of a MySQL string literal.  To get a literal backslash character in a string literal, we need to two escape the backslash with another backslash character... two backslashes, e.g.  `SELECT '\\'`.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL string literal, the backslash character needs to be escaped, by preceding it with another backslash.

As a simple demonstration...

```
SELECT 'C:\foo'   AS one_backslash
     , 'C:\\foo'  AS two_backslash
```

---

Suggestion:

Test expressions with a SELECT statement before running an UPDATE

```
SELECT REPLACE(path, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', '%APPDATA%') AS new_path
  FROM software s 
 WHERE path LIKE '%C:\\Program Files (x86)%'
```

Comment: Nice catch...I missed that +1

Comment: Above SQL not working... I used below SQL as well and its giving 0 records ... select * From software
                         where path like '%C:\\%' ;

Comment: BTW I am using Maria 5.5.6 and Workbench as client.

Comment: @Shatru: we would expect the SQL to return 0 rows when the table does not contain any rows that satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause. Again, I recommend testing expressions (including string literals) in a `SELECT` statement  For example, what value does this query return  `SELECT '%C:\\%'` ?  Is workbench or something else in the execution path interpreting the string and consuming backslashes? Try `SELECT '%C:\\\\%', '%C:\\\\\\\\%'` to figure out how many backslashes are needed in the original string in your client in order to get a single backslash character in MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: @Shatru:  In some bash shell scripts, using heredocs and calling mysql command line client, I have to use eight (8) backslash characters to get two backslash characters in SQL text passed to MySQL, so that MySQL sees a single backslash character.